# Вопрос насколько реален проект python qivy или что лучше

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, apk, мобильные-приложения

Есть пробное задания сделать лото приложения или сайт. Нашел библиотеку Qivy для создания apk приложения на python,вот в чём вопрос заключается реально ли по срокам сделать лото(по типу рус.лото) на данном фреймворки за месяц хотя бы что-то на это похожее на рус.лото или зделать сайт на django?В моём арсенали html css python и немного знаю django.Реально ли за месяц не зная данную библиотеку и не имея опыта в создании приложений это делать?И подходит ли данная библиотека для этого?Если нет то какие библиотеки на которые можно потратить не более месяца для создания лото вы посоветуете.Или это плохая идея и легче сделать сайт?

Comment: Никто не знает насколько быстро именно вы освоите нужные технологии. Совет - пробуйте делать пробное задание в любом случае, даже если не успеете по срокам - получите опыт. Kivy для тестового не советую, в реальных проектах для Android все-таки больше используется Java/Kotlin. Лучше делайте на django, если уже есть какой-то опыт, так больше шансов уложиться в срок.

Comment: @insolor Я просто не разу не занимался адаптивной вёрсткой, и в моих глазах и по рассказам знакомого  это что-то инородное. qivy настолько плохая библиотека и не даст возможность сделать казино?Просто мне кажется в приложении сделать лото легче и быстрее, или мои догадки не верны?Простите если сильно глупые вопросы ибо не разу не делал мини игры на сайте и не занимался созданием приложения

Comment: Kivy не плохая библиотека, казино вы на ней сделаете, но полученные знания в итоге вам вряд ли где-то пригодятся кроме хобби проектов. Исторически так сложилось, что для Android обычно используются Java или Kotlin. По поводу верстки: не умеете адаптивную верстку - делайте как умеете. Не думаю, что на джуна от вас будут требовать каких-то супер знаний.

Comment: FENIX ф вы специально искажаете название фреймворка? Вам сказали как он правильно называется вы всё равно искажаете, с таким подходом вы вряд ли где то добьётесь нормальных результатов.

Comment: P.S. есть фреймворк Kivy и есть Qiwi кошелёк, вы про что конкретно говорите? Кошелёк умеет APK собирать?